# In Grafana, how to build a data link to filter current dashboard when there is more than one variable?

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I'm using Grafana v8.3.4 (a551d74b11)

I've a dashboard with many variables (filters). One of those is for exemple TransactionType.

I would like my charts to filter on click.

For example with a pie chart using TransactionType, I want to filter the TransactionType variable ,when I click in one of the element of the pie chart, by this element.

The closest feature I found is to use [data link](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/linking/data-links/).

So far I tried in the pie chart the two data link there after.
The syntax is OK but the effect is not doing what i’m expecting.

a)

```
/d/${__dashboard.uid}﻿/${__dashboard}?var-TransactionType=${__series.name}
```

For this one the data link apply the filter on TransactionType but clear all the other filters variables, even clear the `All`, so the dashboard is in error.

b)

```
/d/${__dashboard.uid}﻿/${__dashboard}?${__all_variables}&var-TransactionType=${__series.name}
```

this one apply all filters first then add the TransactionType filter but, it keep the previous `All` value, so the filter become `All + value`, that don’t work, the dashboard is in error too.

==> Is there a way to keep all the existing variable filter unchanged and replace the value for one variable filter ?

Answer (score 0):

move var-TransactionType=${__series.name} before ${__all_variables}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).